# NSKVODeallocate Crash

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Refer to logs captured by crash lytics:

The issue is related to UITableView:

Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
An instance 0x106107c00 of class UITableView was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info:  (  Context: 0x0, Property: 0x174255ea0>  Context: 0x0, Property: 0x1702433c0> )

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1816741c0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1800ac55c objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x181674108 -[NSException initWithCoder:]
3  Foundation                     0x1820c1df4 NSKVODeallocate
4  liboainject.dylib              0x101f5a16c (Missing)
5  CoreFoundation                 0x1815d07b8 -[__NSOrderedSetI dealloc]
6  liboainject.dylib              0x101f5a114 (Missing)
7  liboainject.dylib              0x101f589d4 (Missing)
8  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1800aaf10 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*)
9  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1800b76e0 objc_destructInstance
10 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1800b7744 object_dispose
11 liboainject.dylib              0x101f5a16c (Missing)
12 CoreFoundation                 0x181551d74 -[__NSArrayI dealloc]
13 liboainject.dylib              0x101f5a114 (Missing)
14 liboainject.dylib              0x101f589d4 (Missing)
15 UIKit                          0x18793ae90 -[_UITraitStorageList .cxx_destruct]
16 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1800aaf10 object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*)
17 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1800b76e0 objc_destructInstance
18 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1800b7744 object_dispose
19 liboainject.dylib              0x101f5a16c (Missing)
20 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1800bce20 _object_remove_assocations
21 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1800b76ec objc_destructInstance
22 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1800b7744 object_dispose
23 UIKit                          0x18785afe0 -[UIResponder dealloc]
24 UIKit                          0x1874bb154 -[UIView dealloc]
25 liboainject.dylib              0x101f5a16c (Missing)
26 libobjc.A.dylib                0x1800c5fe0 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*)
27 liboainject.dylib              0x101f5931c (Missing)
28 CoreFoundation                 0x18154ddb8 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop
29 CoreFoundation                 0x18161fb20 __CFRunLoopRun
30 CoreFoundation                 0x18154e048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
31 GraphicsServices               0x182fd1198 GSEventRunModal
32 UIKit                          0x187528628 -[UIApplication _run]
33 UIKit                          0x187523360 UIApplicationMain
34 newbe                          0x1002fbe4c main (AppDelegate.swift:22)
35 libdyld.dylib                  0x1805305b8 start
```

Comment: Well what is your question ? Your crash log tells you exactly what is wrong with your code: don't forget to unregister your observers in dealloc ! Without you showing your code, there is nothing more to say.

Comment: Also, it looks like you forgot to upload your dSYM files to crashlytics, which is why you're seeing all theses `(Missing)`. Check their doc for how you can fix this problem.